# O-order of GC algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, garbage-collection

Are the garbage collection algorithms polynomial or exponential?
If polynomial - would they be linear with heap size or quadratic?
An initial understanding tells me that the Parallel and CMS GC would be linear with the number of objects that need to be visited.

But would appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: Um...linear?  Anything else would be kind of catastrophic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time complexity is for an ideal machine.  In reality CPUs have caches of a relatively limited size and GC can access memory quite randomly and in effeciently.

The GC algo are O(n) but the size of your data vs CPU cache and even how randomly your data is arranged do matter. e.g. your GC has to do more work if there is lots of references from old gen to new gen.

Comment: Would the search for references from new-> or old->new tend to make the GC process quadratic?

Comment: @IUnknown if it were implemented badly, but it's not that bad..  The main difference is it need more record keeping and memory as overhead.